# How to improve the integration accuracy without significant reduction in the speed?

Tags: numerical-integration, performance-tuning

Consider some distribution:

```
distributionData = {{0., 0.06474882209732317}, {0.2, 
    0.1435339764043562}, {0.4, 
    0.22231913071138915}, {0.6000000000000001, 
    0.2713804312539526}, {0.8, 0.2859633229509996}, 
     {1., 0.29344892141918905}, {1.2000000000000002, 
    0.2920465785741585}, {1.4000000000000001, 
    0.2840990325637182}, {1.6, 0.27057258391002026}, 
     {1.8, 0.24865771333607997}, {2., 0.2243439564025267}, {2.2, 
    0.20619980461385345}, {2.4000000000000004, 
    0.19381462505268862}, {2.6, 0.1799730546306832}, 
     {2.8000000000000003, 0.16301982408750582}, {3., 
    0.14441132428399708}, {3.2, 
    0.12892746976432007}, {3.4000000000000004, 0.11703710834373694}, 
     {3.6, 0.10554516110211734}, {3.8000000000000003, 
    0.09379332486241404}, {4., 0.0818520332609257}, {4.2, 
    0.07183129422407594}, {4.4, 0.06466639569368737}, 
     {4.6000000000000005, 0.05852745715481098}, {4.800000000000001, 
    0.05361405554177379}, {5., 0.049835518804886215}, {5.2, 
    0.04603566181597916}, 
     {5.4, 0.04219096456792591}, {5.6000000000000005, 
    0.038322747312745944}, {5.800000000000001, 
    0.03507631130158541}, {6., 0.032538896781054656}, 
     {6.2, 0.03010754844686558}, {6.4, 
    0.027743811708388265}, {6.6000000000000005, 
    0.025428860625891354}, {6.800000000000001, 0.023489196334754218}, 
     {7., 0.022101482741853716}, {7.2, 0.02090728614729504}, {7.4, 
    0.01992009505620333}, {7.6000000000000005, 0.019123056377113597}, 
     {7.800000000000001, 0.018178296900151804}, {8., 
    0.01692763352834218}, {8.200000000000001, 
    0.015518787059556777}, {8.4, 0.014284491324001126}, 
     {8.6, 0.013247565210035986}, {8.8, 0.012268682529853237}, {9., 
    0.011413018330632034}, {9.200000000000001, 0.010645348066950744}, 
     {9.4, 0.009922484542720655}, {9.600000000000001, 
    0.00926480808599114}, {9.8, 0.008638959414182086}, {10., 
    0.00814196274487214}, 
     {10.200000000000001, 0.007762370621190225}, {10.4, 
    0.007398956606470757}, {10.600000000000001, 
    0.007068537085912465}, {10.8, 0.006754933950552907}, 
     {11., 0.006387275354921172}, {11.200000000000001, 
    0.005959003771878196}, {11.4, 
    0.005551557017571054}, {11.600000000000001, 0.005237470194722932}, 
     {11.8, 0.004989360947458945}, {12., 
    0.0047462824899109}, {12.200000000000001, 
    0.004510444824580377}, {12.4, 0.004282111689598062}, 
     {12.600000000000001, 0.004108775170521445}, {12.8, 
    0.003985140739503903}, {13., 
    0.003812984643094052}, {13.200000000000001, 
    0.0035433476630190772}, 
     {13.4, 0.0032247514646712924}, {13.600000000000001, 
    0.0029691239454620174}, {13.8, 0.0027835206532271463}, {14., 
    0.002625185876587628}, 
     {14.200000000000001, 0.002534064785821286}, {14.4, 
    0.002489944413168658}, {14.600000000000001, 
    0.00251411201721351}, {14.8, 0.0026355264905019585}, 
     {15., 0.002767890061578616}, {15.200000000000001, 
    0.0027265785893079483}, {15.4, 
    0.002529601868447868}, {15.600000000000001, 
    0.0023343049244150707}, 
     {15.8, 0.0021423330605108578}, {16., 
    0.001952006499907943}, {16.2, 
    0.0017957101391592567}, {16.400000000000002, 
    0.001676946969909395}, 
     {16.6, 0.0015697221958929717}, {16.8, 
    0.0014885732609882295}, {17., 0.0014254647616063294}, {17.2, 
    0.001350196156777002}, 
     {17.400000000000002, 0.0012577919728160639}, {17.6, 
    0.001165737058365662}, {17.8, 0.0011215982411960387}, {18., 
    0.0011200507781124797}, 
     {18.2, 0.0011095173027579615}, {18.400000000000002, 
    0.001081453976823827}, {18.6, 0.001044846812581037}, {18.8, 
    0.0010249940596810398}, 
     {19., 0.0010234702141204964}, {19.200000000000003, 
    0.0010121188593757622}, {19.400000000000002, 
    0.000964637565662243}, {19.6, 0.0008924283381607902}, 
     {19.8, 0.00084648720891351}, {20., 
    0.0008371786783417011}, {20.200000000000003, 
    0.0008379701202670879}, {20.400000000000002, 
    0.0008365302863782252}, 
     {20.6, 0.0008331237045992151}, {20.8, 
    0.0008218955984987578}, {21., 
    0.0007956272620170017}, {21.200000000000003, 
    0.0007621402194753926}, 
     {21.400000000000002, 0.0007340650449819739}, {21.6, 
    0.000711862595800475}, {21.8, 0.000694556612724945}, {22., 
    0.0006909826775659336}, 
     {22.200000000000003, 
    0.0006967051814812019}, {22.400000000000002, 
    0.0006839909803247744}, {22.6, 0.0006458291890290979}, {22.8, 
    0.000600817898945626}, 
     {23., 0.0005570876279773298}, {23.200000000000003, 
    0.0005144769898444512}, {23.400000000000002, 
    0.0004972625751360929}, {23.6, 0.0005281955478650085}, 
     {23.8, 0.0005818796846066788}, {24., 
    0.0005979059984581492}, {24.200000000000003, 
    0.0005733944350522276}, {24.400000000000002, 
    0.0005469065313562248}, 
     {24.6, 0.0005231535117655811}, {24.8, 
    0.0005012316622031877}, {25., 
    0.0004736852300440124}, {25.200000000000003, 
    0.00043845415722172746}, 
     {25.400000000000002, 0.00040186506726851037}, {25.6, 
    0.00037053822339153347}, {25.8, 0.00034377158465540253}, {26., 
    0.000325366321961237}, 
     {26.200000000000003, 
    0.00032259282293339576}, {26.400000000000002, 
    0.0003270897115299132}, {26.6, 0.0003117644178502639}, {26.8, 
    0.00027527022198887177}, 
     {27., 0.00024480183581701174}, {27.200000000000003, 
    0.00023615420268571858}, {27.400000000000002, 
    0.00024195479299988514}, {27.6, 0.00024303236366731196}, 
     {27.8, 0.00023772189378049507}, {28., 
    0.0002324133028095936}, {28.200000000000003, 
    0.00023894020603411507}, {28.400000000000002, 
    0.0002556357036306401}, 
     {28.6, 0.0002639897487406163}, {28.8, 
    0.0002569628741463812}, {29., 
    0.00024289653233448372}, {29.200000000000003, 
    0.0002325698416848505}, 
     {29.400000000000002, 0.0002262054420563917}, {29.6, 
    0.00021854173057866242}, {29.8, 0.00020647034594758394}, {30., 
    0.0001915132398713364}, 
     {30.200000000000003, 
    0.00018069432344928885}, {30.400000000000002, 
    0.00017541677243329668}, {30.6, 0.00017112177455639308}, {30.8, 
    0.0001639898541841569}, 
     {31., 0.00015444163392935447}, {31.200000000000003, 
    0.00014681264880797167}, {31.400000000000002, 
    0.0001426747508573996}, {31.6, 0.0001401087049442184}, 
     {31.8, 0.00014120284127020023}, {32., 
    0.00014614478473581402}, {32.2, 0.00014951150780947886}, {32.4, 
    0.00014788042892986114}, 
     {32.6, 0.00014301439338937835}, {32.800000000000004, 
    0.00013718071748408816}, {33., 0.00013006405582864105}, {33.2, 
    0.00012286949536800622}, 
     {33.4, 0.00011720000631371386}, {33.6, 
    0.00011281814208560132}, {33.800000000000004, 
    0.00010635231437691231}, {34., 0.00009614629557709086}, 
     {34.2, 0.00008428404916671251}, {34.4, 
    0.00008993772823554732}, {34.6, 
    0.0001138625398788725}, {34.800000000000004, 
    0.0001345900967584055}, 
     {35., 0.00014434323522537825}, {35.2, 
    0.0001470744171388587}, {35.4, 0.00014192759187901593}, {35.6, 
    0.00012643725955944482}, 
     {35.800000000000004, 0.00010897195933184939}, {36., 
    0.00009451377841899783}, {36.2, 0.00008257218484250931}, {36.4, 
    0.00007120719498080343}, 
     {36.6, 0.00006086344907332083}, {36.800000000000004, 
    0.00005096434340527963}, {37., 0.00005619606869388283}, {37.2, 
    0.00007708964280328146}, 
     {37.4, 0.00009431954146091426}, {37.6, 
    0.00010013780675727225}, {37.800000000000004, 
    0.00009873913200826995}, {38., 0.00008796313966884207}, 
     {38.2, 0.00006499402399591319}, {38.400000000000006, 
    0.000043486348795338644}, {38.6, 0.00004705755488246113}, 
     {38.800000000000004, 0.00007143039604185412}, {39., 
    0.00008386772541948707}, {39.2, 
    0.00007544013780763052}, {39.400000000000006, 
    0.00005808314498804449}, 
     {39.6, 0.00004726210383635683}, {39.800000000000004, 
    0.00004315477339855982}, {40., 0.00004096762298162199}, {40.2, 
    0.000043426821767914235}, 
     {40.400000000000006, 0.00004878994878257}, {40.6, 
    0.00005660518686075418}, {40.800000000000004, 
    0.00006757835054246212}, {41., 0.00007729774195820529}, 
     {41.2, 0.00007600697421217033}, {41.400000000000006, 
    0.00006566563411031604}, {41.6, 
    0.00005633431364401515}, {41.800000000000004, 
    0.0000487460125861131}, 
     {42., 0.00004189071130105732}, {42.2, 
    0.00004473829237107008}, {42.400000000000006, 
    0.00005747717373205249}, {42.6, 0.00006490222012030903}, 
     {42.800000000000004, 0.00005793991358594689}, {43., 
    0.00004209250703759328}, {43.2, 
    0.00003421832872760131}, {43.400000000000006, 
    0.00003651509095653293}, 
     {43.6, 0.00004025709486247871}, {43.800000000000004, 
    0.00003994064152016939}, {44., 0.00003631820155315211}, {44.2, 
    0.000033942271811918935}, 
     {44.400000000000006, 0.00003369025356070546}, {44.6, 
    0.000034315636573727446}, {44.800000000000004, 
    0.00003255031799113124}, 
     {45., 0.000028366189575663255}, {45.2, 
    0.00002642123533736831}, {45.400000000000006, 
    0.000030291839667456596}, {45.6, 0.0000377107201515009}, 
     {45.800000000000004, 0.0000382703346102378}, {46., 
    0.00003016215223331635}, {46.2, 
    0.000020968481284153905}, {46.400000000000006, 
    0.00001552432521610211}, 
     {46.6, 0.000013106641791050664}, {46.800000000000004, 
    0.000013850035534920375}, {47., 0.000019912226168957144}, {47.2, 
    0.000028132136524240305}, 
     {47.400000000000006, 0.00003320177994841226}, {47.6, 
    0.00003510789326468317}, {47.800000000000004, 
    0.00003481523259604383}, {48., 0.000029021568360351945}, 
     {48.2, 0.000019912411365727413}, {48.400000000000006, 
    0.000014331766033197474}, {48.6, 0.00001316850373552018}, 
     {48.800000000000004, 0.000012873798191630357}, {49., 
    0.00001247765364239998}, {49.2, 0.000012000384706799583}, 
     {49.400000000000006, 0.000012790433765489233}, {49.6, 
    0.00001568653679709409}, {49.800000000000004, 
    0.000019413695783046367}, 
     {50., 0.000020767283293498943}, {50.2, 
    0.00001975497935272974}, {50.400000000000006, 
    0.00001943860177054408}, {50.6, 0.000020841744272873003}, 
     {50.800000000000004, 0.00002326848050113313}, {51., 
    0.000021230873778737924}, {51.2, 
    0.000013655801532013774}, {51.400000000000006, 
    6.261923253397366*^-6}, 
     {51.6, 4.907340100385922*^-6}, {51.800000000000004, 
    8.337735531198783*^-6}, {52., 9.728144162310393*^-6}, {52.2, 
    7.76980050441537*^-6}, 
     {52.400000000000006, 4.518302676016293*^-6}, {52.6, 
    2.73075866543848*^-6}, {52.800000000000004, 
    2.3915571538806297*^-6}, {53., 2.7929544873252636*^-6}, 
     {53.2, 4.991270064067334*^-6}, {53.400000000000006, 
    8.245905039104276*^-6}, {53.6, 
    9.934058531049866*^-6}, {53.800000000000004, 
    9.696924461035674*^-6}, 
     {54., 9.24929908519841*^-6}, {54.2, 
    9.491122795254228*^-6}, {54.400000000000006, 
    0.00001027408081815778}, {54.6, 0.000011020302885269638}, 
     {54.800000000000004, 0.000011706947303627054}, {55., 
    0.000012350365410219822}, {55.2, 0.000011867061643466598}, 
     {55.400000000000006, 0.000010277420622169185}, {55.6, 
    8.989204509137367*^-6}, {55.800000000000004, 
    8.419389249307674*^-6}, {56., 8.266549934414586*^-6}, 
     {56.2, 9.180169307074078*^-6}, {56.400000000000006, 
    0.000011392663894579835}, {56.6, 0.000013209826749228934}, 
     {56.800000000000004, 0.000012206268645097419}, {57., 
    9.009737842335671*^-6}, {57.2, 
    7.778112858590172*^-6}, {57.400000000000006, 
    9.695201306002688*^-6}, 
     {57.6, 0.000012710604377352152}, {57.800000000000004, 
    0.000012375986489136924}, {58., 8.77684062956163*^-6}, {58.2, 
    6.7783404788304045*^-6}, 
     {58.400000000000006, 8.528374487781133*^-6}, {58.6, 
    0.000012426296947569472}, {58.800000000000004, 
    0.00001494384789657572}, {59., 0.000015795272306846502}, 
     {59.2, 0.000016017658857082477}, {59.400000000000006, 
    0.000014747362308806776}, {59.6, 0.000012327665494101093}, 
     {59.800000000000004, 9.907968679395322*^-6}, {60., 
    7.4882718646896385*^-6}};
distribution[Ex_] = 
 Interpolation[distributionData, InterpolationOrder -> 1][Ex]
```

Next, consider some function `DfDExDq2`:

```
Rn = 25.52;
sn = 0.52;
Fnucleus[q2_] = (3 SphericalBesselJ[1, Sqrt[q2] Rn])/(Sqrt[q2]*Rn)
    Exp[-((q2*sn^2)/2)];
Er[q2_, mf_] = q2/(2*mf);
DfDExDq2[q2_, Ex_, mZ_, mN_] = 
  10^-3. Fnucleus[
    q2]^2 (2/q2 - 1/(mZ*Ex) + 
     mN^2/(2*mZ*q2*
       Ex^2)*(Er[q2, mZ] - mZ - 2*Ex + mN^2 (Er[q2, mZ] - mZ)/q2));
```

It is a function of two parameters `mZ`,`mN`, and two variables `q2`,`Ex` over which I need to integrate. The domain of definition of `q2`, `Ex` is

```
    Q2max[Ex_, mZ_, 
   mN_] = (Ex Sqrt[4 Ex^2 mZ^2 - 4 Ex mZ mN^2 - 4 mZ^2 mN^2 + mN^4] + 
     2 Ex^2 mZ - Ex mN^2 - mZ mN^2)/(2 Ex + mZ);
Q2minTemp[Ex_, mZ_, 
   mN_] = -((Ex (Sqrt[
           4 Ex^2 mZ^2 - 4 Ex mZ mN^2 - 4 mZ^2 mN^2 + mN^4] + mN^2) - 
       2 Ex^2 mZ + mZ mN^2)/(2 Ex + mZ));
Q2minLimit[Ex_, mZ_, mN_] = 
  Assuming[Ex > 0 && mZ > 0, 
   Simplify[Normal@Series[Q2minTemp[Ex, mZ, mN], {mN, 0, 4}]]];
Q2min[Ex_, mZ_, mN_] = 
  If[mN/Ex > 10^-2, Q2minTemp[Ex, mZ, mN], Q2minLimit[Ex, mZ, mN]];
Exmin[mZ_, mN_] = (2 mZ mN + mN^2)/(2 mZ);
Exmax = 60;
```

There is a problem with the exact expression for $q^{2}_{\text{min}}$, `Q2minTemp`. Namely, for small ratios `mN/Ex` Mathematica sets it to zero because of lack of precision, whereas it actually tends to `Q2minLimit`. Therefore, I have defined a new function `Q2min`.

Now, I want to integrate `DfDExDq2` using different methods:

```
mZval=1;
f[mN_, method_] := 
 NIntegrate[
  DfDExDq2[q2, Ex, mZval, mN]*distribution[Ex], {Ex, Exmin[mZval, mN],
    Exmax}, {q2, Q2min[Ex, mZval, mN], Q2max[Ex, mZval, mN]}, 
  Method -> method]
Join[{{"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(m\), \(N\)]\)", "Method", 
    "{Integral value,time}"}}, 
  Flatten[Table[{mN, method, 
     f[mN, method] // AbsoluteTiming}, {mN, {10^-3, 
      2}}, {method, {Automatic, "InterpolationPointsSubdivision", 
      "AdaptiveMonteCarlo"}}], {1, 2}]] // TableForm
```

[image]

The Monte-Carlo method is moderately fast, although it also took a bunch of time to calculate. In addition, it has a large error:

```
{f[10^-3,"AdaptiveMonteCarlo"],f[10^-3,"AdaptiveMonteCarlo"],f[10^-3,"AdaptiveMonteCarlo"],f[10^-3,"AdaptiveMonteCarlo"],f[10^-3,"AdaptiveMonteCarlo"]}
```

> {0.0119318, 0.0100804, 0.0158859, 0.00586925, 0.00829546}

Maybe the problem with MonteCarlo is that the q2 integral is maximal near small q2 (i.e. when Q2 is close to Q2minLimit), and Monte Carlo sampling just does not hit there from time to time.

Could you please tell me:

1. Whether it is possible to improve the integration speed for any of the methods?
2. If it is not possible, how to improve the accuracy of MonteCarlo without a significant reduction in the actual speed?

**Update**.

It seems that I have found a brute-force way to improve the speed of integration while keeping the accuracy not so bad. Instead of performing the double integration, I first perform the table of the integrals over `q2` assuming `Ex` to be a parameter, and then interpolate it and integrate over `Ex`:

```
f2[mN_, method_] := Block[{},
  integral[Ex_] := 
   If[Exmin[mZval, mN] < Exmax, 
    Quiet[NIntegrate[
      DfDExDq2[q2, Ex, mZval, mN], {q2, Q2min[Ex, mZval, mN], 
       Q2max[Ex, mZval, mN]}, Method -> method]], 0];
  fint[Ex_] = 
   distribution[Ex]*
    Interpolation[
      ParallelTable[{Ex, Quiet[integral[Ex]]}, {Ex, 
        1.01 Exmin[mZval, mN], Exmax, (Exmax - 1.01 Exmin[mZval, mN])/
        100}], InterpolationOrder -> 1][Ex];
  NIntegrate[fint[Ex], {Ex, Exmin[mZval, mN], Exmax}, 
   Method -> "InterpolationPointsSubdivision"]
  ]

Join[{{"mN", "f,AdaptiveMonteCarlo", "f,Automatic", "f2,Automatic"}}, 
  Table[{mN, f[mN, "AdaptiveMonteCarlo"] // AbsoluteTiming, 
    f[mN, Automatic] // AbsoluteTiming, 
    f2[mN, Automatic] // AbsoluteTiming}, {mN, {10^-3, 10^-2, 10^-1, 
     1, 5, 7}}]] // TableForm
```

[image]

The problem is that the deviation grows once increasing `mZval`, and it is not known to me which value is correct. Say, if setting it to 40 and, e.g., mN to 7, I get

```
f2[7, "AdaptiveMonteCarlo"]
f[7, Automatic]
```

> 2.67662*10^-40

> 1.60291*10^-40

Comment: Hm. I think `mZval` is undefined.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher : Excuse me. I have added mZval =1 to the code.

Comment: That would have been also my first guess! XD

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher : there is another misprint: Fnucleus[
    q2] in DfDExDq2 must be squared.

Comment: Some general remark: Your functions seems to behave singularly or oscillatory only around the coordinate axis. So it is a good idea for non-adaptive algorithms (e.g., Monte Carlo) to decompose the integration domain into regions of varying "difficulty". Treat the easy regions (where the function is quite smooth) by methods like Gauss quadrature. And use Monte Carlo only in the diffcult regions. Then the brute-force power of Monte Carlo is applied only where needed.

Comment: However, Monte Carlo's convergence rate should be something like $n^{-1/2}$, where $n$ is the number of samples. So the runtime should roughly scale with the square of the precision. That is good in very high-dimensional contexts, but quite bad in low-dimension contexts like this one. In low dimensions I expect "classical" adaptive quadrature rules to work better. Have you tried the `"LocalAdaptive"` method?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher : Thanks for the suggestions. As for the "LocalAdaptive", it works very-very slow (much slower than the other methods).

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher : I have found a way to improve speed without significant loss in accuracy, please take a look at the update. It is interesting whether the new method gives more accurate results than the old method with the Automatic integration method.

Comment: Seems, you can do the integration over q2 analytically. Got a result with`Integrate[DfDExDq2[q2, Ex, mZval, mN]*distribution[Ex], q2]` .  Therefor simplified with Together `DfDExDq2[q2_, Ex_, mZ_, mN_] = 
 10^-3 Fnucleus[q2]^2 (2/q2 - 1/(mZ*Ex) + 
     mN^2/(2*mZ*q2*Ex^2)*(Er[q2, mZ] - mZ - 2*Ex + 
        mN^2 (Er[q2, mZ] - mZ)/q2)) // Together` and used rational numbers not reals all over.